# Maven command line: How to split a unified jar file into 2 separate parts?

Tags: python-2.7, maven, intellij-idea, jar

Here is the context: I am working with **2 projects** - MAIN and TESTS classes **in 2 separate packages**. In my unique pom.xml file which is in the same package as the MAIN classes, I have added the TESTS files using the following plugins & goals:

- build-helper-maven-plugin & add-source - and add the path of the path of the TESTS files.
- maven-resources-plugin & copy-resources
- maven-assembly-plugin & single

I was so far, successful to build 1 jar file - in a python script - that contains the MAIN and the TESTS with the help of the 3 named plugins and a pom file in the MAIN - in which the TESTS were added as resources. 
My goal is to build **2 separate jar files - MAIN and TESTS**, from the one I just built. But I don't know how.

**EDIT:**

**pom.xml of Parent Modules:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- project coordinates -->
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
            <module>app</module>
            <module>util</module>
    </modules>
```

**pom of First Child Module:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <parent>
            <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>multi-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>util</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.12</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Class of First Child module:**

```
    package com.xyz.util;

public class UserMsg {

        public static String getMessage() {
               return(" Hello World!");
        }
}
```

**pom of Second Child Module:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
            <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>multi-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>util</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Class of Second Child module:**

```
   package com.xyz;

import com.xyz.util.*;

public class App {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(UserMsg.getMessage());
        }

}
```

**Results:**

1. I succeeded building both jar files while in the parent directory.
2. Also, one jar that contains all files - from both modules while in either of the 2 modules and assured that the dependency is set.

**Goal:**

1. I am looking to split the "combined" ones into 2 jar files, once it is built and a request is done, to do so.
2. Also, to create the jar file of the module "app" that depends on the "util" ones, while positioning in the app directory and NOT in the ROOT directory that will create both of them. I want this jar to be different from the "combined" ones. For example, not to include all files from "util".

**NOTE:** When I add the dependency or the path of resources in a plugin as shown below, it doesn't work.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${basedir}/../pathToNeededClassFiles</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**Resust of** `mvn package -pl :app` when I run on my project

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building app 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ com/xyz/multi-app/1.0/multi-app-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.110 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-11T11:29:27-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/148M
[INFO]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xyz:app:jar:1.0: 
Failed to collect dependencies at com.xyz:util:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.xyz:util:jar:1.0: 
Could not find artifact com.xyz:multi-app:pom:1.0: in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks to me like you overcomplicated your project with all those plugins. Depending on your folder structure it should work out of the box already without adding those three plugins and if you add https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

Comment: Thanks, Robert for your answer. But, this is working for me. The project, I am working on is designed the way I tried to explain above: 2 separate packages.And so far all the tests classes are required to run the MAIN classes. And moving the tests classes will no longer respect the inherent design - that I am not allowed to modify.Except adding xml files & a script. On the other hand, I was trying this example: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_build_more_than_one_project_at_once (in the section:How do I build more than one project at once?)But not working yet

Comment: When trying the multi-module approach given in the link of my previous comment, I was getting these [WARNING] & [ERROR]  Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for appGrId:appGrID:jar:1.0.1
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 69, column 12
[ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='appGrId:appTests:1.0.1'}' and 'Vertex{label='appGrId:app:1.0.1'}' introduces to cycle in the graph appGrId:app:1.0.1 --> appGrId:appTests:1.0.1 --> appGrId:app:1.0.1 @

Comment: Also, the problem in that example is the 2 considered projects - app and wep-app - they both have a main class. whereas in my case the tests do not have a main.

Comment: can you share your project? or have a downloadable simplified example?

Comment: Sorry Robert, for my late reply. I am going to update my question and include it. Thanks

Comment: Regarding goal #1 I still don't understand. If you run `mvn package` from the root you get the 2 separate jars, right? Regarding #2 not possible by design. What you can do is `mvn package -pl :app` from the root, so only the app is built. You chose for a multiproject setup meaning the intention is to build it all together. ps. your `add-sources` is a sign there's something wrong with the project setup. It should have been a dependency.

Comment: That's right Robert - Regarding goal #1. And I got 2 separate jars from the root. But what I would like to get is also 2 separate jars but from the combined ones. Let's say, I have built a combined jar in version 0.0.1.0 which is in archive. And if currently, we're at version 0.0.1.1, that means from the root, I would get 2 separate jars of version 0.0.1.1 while I wanted the 0.0.1.0 ones. I want to be able to pull the combined ones from the archive and split it. Regarding #2, do you mean my design or maven design? I'm going to try `mvn package -pl :app` from the root. Thanks a lot, Robert

Comment: I have added the result of `mvn package -pl :app` in the question. Thanks for your help, Robert.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g6uo35fb627lix/multi-app.zip?dl=0 is how I would have solved it (2 jars for app). `mvn package -pl :app -amd` (also-make-dependencies) will make sure that app can be built, but in this case the result is th same as `mvn package`.

Comment: Hi Robert, I am still getting the same error when I run the same command on my project. I also, tried to copy the depended jar into the lib of the app module before adding a repository with an "id and url" since it was unable to find the jar in the maven repo. But still not working. It is telling me that it couldn't find it in that lib whereas it is in there.

Comment: maybe a chat works better. I'm at freenode at #maven

Comment: I just get the goal 2 - app jar - by pursuing the idea of copying it into the lib folder of the app module. For that, I had to add scope system and the path where I copied the jar into a systemPath tag. But it needs some improvements. Because got a [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.xyz:app:jar:1.0. In the attempt of solving by replaced the hard coded path by using `${basedir}/app/util.jar`. It was still not happy, so I `${basedir}/app/*.jar` but it was highlighted in red

Comment: `java -cp app\target\app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-combined.jar com.xyz.App` says `Hello World!`. Please, don't use scope:system, since lib is just a standard compile/runtime dependency!

Comment: Why did you use the combined jar? It only depends on `util` right? Thanks

Comment: Because only the combined.jar contains all the required classes. At runtime there's no such thing as dependencies, they only exist within the Maven context.